# How could I archieve this design with bootstrap 5? Spans stacked, one is inside the container one outside

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Im trying to archieve this particular design in Bootstrap 5.3.

[image]

This should be over the showcase, the code for the showcase that should be underneath the text:

```
    <div class="showcase d-flex flex-column">

        <div class="container p-4">
            <div class="row showcase-row mt-5 gap-lg-0 gap-5">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-12 showcase-item">
                    <h4>BMW 420i</h4>
                    <h5>M Sport</h5>
                    <img src="/app/static/img/togg art.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-12 showcase-item">
                    <h4>Mercedes-Benz GLB</h4>
                    <h5>200 AMG</h5>
                    <img src="/app/static/img/8.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-12 showcase-item">
                    <h4>Audi E-Tron GT</h4>
                    <h5>GT Quattro</h5>
                    <img src="/app/static/img/9.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-12 showcase-item">
                    <h4>Ferrari F8</h4>
                    <h5>Tributo</h5>
                    <img src="/app/static/img/4.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-12 showcase-item">
                    <h4>Lamborghini Aventador</h4>
                    <h5>LP750-4</h5>
                    <img src="/app/static/img/5.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-12 showcase-item">
                    <h4>Aston Martin Vantage</h4>
                    <h5>V8 Vantage Roadster</h5>
                    <img src="/app/static/img/6.png" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
```

EDIT:

The current solution I found

```
    <span class="text-uppercase fw-bold position-absolute" style="font-size: 210px; opacity: 0.1;">owcase</span>

    <div class="showcase container p-4 d-flex flex-column" style="margin-top: 100px;">
   
        <span class="fs-3 fw-bold">Showcase</span>
        <span class="fs-5 fw-bold" style="opacity: 0.4;">Ads</span>
        
    </div>
```

If you got a better way don't mind to share it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of position relative and z-index

Hope this helps (I have added a padding to body and a margin to section to give an easier to look example)

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

.section {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.back-title {
  color: #ababab;
  font-size: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: -50px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.content-container {
  z-index: 2;
  /** position relative to make z-index work and not modify behavior */
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="section container">
  <h1 class="back-title">
    Showcase
  </h1>
   <div class="content-container row gap-lg-0 gap-5">
     <div class="col-lg-4 col-12 showcase-item">
       <h4>BMW 420i</h4>
       <h5>M Sport</h5>
       <img src="/app/static/img/togg art.png" alt="">
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-4 col-12 showcase-item">
       <h4>Mercedes-Benz GLB</h4>
       <h5>200 AMG</h5>
       <img src="/app/static/img/8.png" alt="">
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-4 col-12 showcase-item">
       <h4>Audi E-Tron GT</h4>
       <h5>GT Quattro</h5>
       <img src="/app/static/img/9.png" alt="">
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-4 col-12 showcase-item">
       <h4>Ferrari F8</h4>
       <h5>Tributo</h5>
       <img src="/app/static/img/4.png" alt="">
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-4 col-12 showcase-item">
       <h4>Lamborghini Aventador</h4>
       <h5>LP750-4</h5>
       <img src="/app/static/img/5.png" alt="">
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-4 col-12 showcase-item">
       <h4>Aston Martin Vantage</h4>
       <h5>V8 Vantage Roadster</h5>
       <img src="/app/static/img/6.png" alt="">
     </div>
  </div>
</section>
```